# Подскажите литературу, или другие источники для изучения NUnit

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, nunit

Подскажите литературу, статьи, сайты или другие источники для изучения NUnit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидный вариант - официальная документация:
https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki

Руководство на Русском языке:
https://riptutorial.com/ru/nunit

Из более серьезных ресурсов, многие рекомендуют эту книгу: https://www.manning.com/books/the-art-of-unit-testing
Перевод: https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/26230428/ (по слухам, перевод не очень)